# ROS Answers SE migration: Foreign Relay

Tags: ros, multimaster

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I have ROS Groovy running on a remote system, but need to have topics available locally as well.

I've looked into multimaster_fkie and foreign_relay. I got foreign_relay working locally (running a ros master on two different ports), however when I did the same setup on two different laptops (connected to the same router / on the same subnet, no firewall) I only could see the topics but not the messages. I have the same issue with multimaster_fkie (which I would not like to use because of the mandatory discovery process, I much prefer foreign_relay's approach to have the remote master specified explicitely).

I saw the other questions on this site, but though the symptoms are precisely the same as answers.ros.org/question/10074/help-troubleshooting-foreign-relay, the fix did not help. I see answers.ros.org/question/12420/foreign_relay-problem has the exact same issue, but no answer. I hope that somebody using foreign_relay successfully could shed some light on this issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/92096/foreign-relay/) by [ps4321](https://answers.ros.org/users/5779/ps4321/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm assuming you have a good reason to want to use foreign_relay instead of relying on the usual ROS infrastructure (ROS_IP, ROS_MASTER).

foreign_relay is a weird duck. First, you need to make sure you start *roscor on each machine before you start your other nodes. foreign_relay attempts to register with the remote master on start and if it is unable to do so, it will fail. Second, if I remember correctly, you need to get rid of the ROS_MASTER export on your computers because it's irrelevant and it confuses the nodes. You may even need to get rid of ROS_IP. This **may** solve your problem.

If not, try debugging using *rostopic info*. Look for topics in the */transport* namespace published by foreign_relay nodes, see who's subscribing to them and who's publishing. You say that you see the topics but not the messages - it could very well be that you see the topics because foreign_relay is advertising them, but it's actually not making a connection with the remote foreign_relay node. The connection won't be made until you publish a message to a relayed topic, but most likely it's because the relays can't talk to one another.

---

Originally posted by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) with karma: 435 on 2013-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ps4321](https://answers.ros.org/users/5779/ps4321/) on 2013-10-23**:
It was actually somehow the other way around - i.e. I had to set ROS_IP (at least for the foreign_relay node) to get it working. Apparently a DNS issue, as there is no DNS entry for the local hostname.

**Comment by [autonomy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3784/autonomy/) on 2013-10-24**:
Ah, so it was probably trying to find a path to "yourhostname", but it didn't know how to do that since it wasn't in the remote computers /etc/hosts file. Glad you solved it.